# pam_sss(su:account) Access denied как исправить ошибку?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

скажите пожалуйста в чем проблема пытаюсь добавить компьютер (linux mint xface) в домен vozrtd.ru используется sssd
не получается залогиниться

ошибки

**linux-test2 su: pam_sss(su:account): Access denied for user galiullin.a@vozrtd.ru: 4 (Системная ошибка)**

**linux-test2 su: FAILED SU (to galiullin.a@vozrtd.ru) supervisor on pts/0**

**linux-test2 su: pam_sss(su:account): Access denied for user galiullin.a@vozrtd.ru: 4 (Системная ошибка)**

какие данные для уточнения нужны ? я пришлю.

Comment: У меня есть плейбук на ansible, который нормально включает ubuntu 20.04 в наш домен. Надо?

Comment: да давайте, буду весьма благодарен, спасибо!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/don-rumata/d4f7ae3761608cde31033b4c894f6501